# Select a COUNT using Django model?

Tags: django

Does anyone know if there's a way to just select the number of rows matching a query in Django? I have a search I've written that splits results into sets of 40, but I'd like to display the total number of results as well. I could to something like len(Model.objects.filter(name__icontains=search)), but it seems like that would be grossly inefficient (since I'm assuming that would generate a "SELECT * FROM model" and then all of the resulting objects). Any suggestions?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

There are two main ways to handle this:

1. Use [Django's count() QuerySet method](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#count) — simply append count() to the end of the appropriate QuerySet
2. Generate an [aggregate over the QuerySet](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-over-a-queryset) — Aggregation is when you "retrieve values that are derived by summarizing or *aggregating* a collection of objects." [Ref: Django Aggregation Documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#aggregation)

The links above are to the applicable sections of Django's documentation.

Comment: Thanks, aggregate did the trick. It's kind of strange; I had to do an aggregate(Count('id')).count() (counting my count?). I'm happy though as long as it's hopefully only pulling up a number though and not all of the data in the table.

Answer (score 55):

Use [`count()`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#count):

```
>>> Model.objects.count()
42
>>> Model.related_set.count()
102
>>> Model.related_set.filter(blah=42).count()
3
```

Answer (score 0):

**For all row count of a table/model:**

**pattern:**

```
Model.objects.count()
```

**example:**

```
User.objects.count()
```

**For specific row count of a table/model:**

**pattern:**

```
Model.objects.filter(user__id=1).count()
```

**example:**

```
User.objects.filter(user__id=1).count()
```

**For further info please visit:** https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/aggregation/