# Is there any function to count a particular choice field from feedback model in django?

Tags: python, django, templates, count, model

```
        class Feedback(models.Model):
        customer_name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
        email = models.EmailField()
        Place = models.CharField(max_length=120)
        Area_Type = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        Electricity = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=[('1','Excellent'),('2','Good'),('3','Bad')])
        Water_Supply = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=[('1', 'Excellent'), ('2', 'Good'), ('3', 'Bad')])
        details = models.TextField()
        Satisfactory_locality = models.BooleanField()
        date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
```

1. I have created the above model in Django.
2. From this I want to count number of feedback choices that are Excellent for Electricity field.
3. Please also tell about how to view this count.
4. Do ask if any more information required.
5. It is showing unresolved attribute when Feedback.objects is used as shown below

```
class ClubChartView(TemplateView):
  template_name = 'clubs/chart.html'
  def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
      context = super().get_context_data()
      context["qs"] = Feedback.objects.all()
      return context
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In django models you can add a property method to a model in which you can reference from anywhere. You can do this by putting the `@property` decorator and then a function.

```
class Feedback(models.Model):
    customer_name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    email = models.EmailField()
    Place = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    Area_Type = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Electricity = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=[('1','Excellent'),('2','Good'),('3','Bad')])
    Water_Supply = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=[('1', 'Excellent'), ('2', 'Good'), ('3', 'Bad')])
    details = models.TextField()
    Satisfactory_locality = models.BooleanField()
    date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)

    @property
    def get_feedback_count(self):
        return Feedback.objects.all().filter(Electricity='1').count()
```

To pass it to the view you can add it to the context in the `views.py` as `count = Feedback.get_feedback_count()`

There is a way to get it from the template using `with` but i forgot right now.

Comment: It is showing an error saying property 'objects' is not callable; can you please help?

Answer (score -1):

this question already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3373565/select-a-count-using-django-model)

examples:

```
>>> Model.objects.count()
42
>>> Model.related_set.count()
102
>>> Model.related_set.filter(blah=42).count()
3
```

Comment: If you believe that a question is already answered somewhere else, that makes it a duplicate. Please do not answer such questions; instead help to keep the site clean by flagging them as duplicates. The point of Stack Overflow is **not** to operate a help desk and directly answer the OP. The point is to cooperate to build a searchable reference Q&A library. For more details, please take the [tour] and read [answer].